# Fill scipy / numpy matrix based on indices and values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a graph of nodes which each represent about 100 voxels in the brain. I partitioned the graph into communities, but now I need to make a correlation matrix where every voxel in a node is connected to every voxel in the nodes that are in the same community. In other words, if nodes 1 and 2 are in the same community, I need a 1 in the matrix between every voxel in node 1 and every voxel in node 2. This takes a very long time with the code below. Does anyone know how to speed this up?

```
for edge in combinations(graph.nodes(),2):
    if partition.get_node_community(edge[0]) == partition.get_node_community(edge[1]): # if nodes are in same community
        voxels1 = np.argwhere(flat_parcel==edge[0]+1) # this is where I find the voxels in each node, and I get the indices for the matrix where I want them.
        voxels2 = np.argwhere(flat_parcel==edge[1]+1)
        for voxel1 in voxels1:
            voxel_matrix[voxel1,voxels2] = 1
```

Thanks for the responses, I think the easiest and fastest solution is to replace the last loop with
    voxel_matrix[np.ix_(voxels1, voxels2)] = 1

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you just want to compute the [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)? Exactly what sort of object is `graph`?

Comment: @ali_m Yup. I have an adjacency matrix of nodes (the graph), and each nodes has about 100 voxels (this is a brain graph). Now I need an adjacency matrix of the voxels, where there is a 1 if voxel i and j were in nodes that were in the same community (which I found via modularity maximization, but that shouldn't matter for this problem). Also, it's a networkx graph...

Comment: Just to get a sense of the scale of the problem, how many nodes are we talking about?

Comment: @senderle 300 nodes. It takes about a day to run as it is now. Most of the time is spent in "for voxel1 in voxels1: voxel_matrix[voxel1,voxels2] = 1". That's where I need a faster method.

Comment: The inner for loop is equivalent to `voxel_matrix[np.ix_(voxels1, voxels2)] = 1` if `voxels1` and `voxels2` are 1d arrays. You probably want to replace `argwhere` by `flatnonzero` to get them to 1d. The question would be somewhat clearer if it was clear if `edge.shape` and `flat_parcel.shape` were given in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that I expect to work for you. It's a stretch on my machine -- even storing two copies of the voxel adjacency matrix (using `dtype=bool`) pushes my (somewhat old) desktop right to the edge of its memory capacity. But I'm assuming that you have a machine capable of handling at least two (300 * 100) ** 2 = 900 MB arrays -- otherwise, you would probably have run into problems before this stage. It takes my desktop about 30 minutes to process 30000 voxels.

This assumes that `voxel_communities` is a simple array containing a community label for each voxel at index `i`. It sounds like you can generate that pretty quickly. It also assumes that voxels are present in only one node.

```
def voxel_adjacency(voxel_communities):
    n_voxels = voxel_communities.size
    comm_labels = sorted(set(voxel_communities))
    comm_counts = [(voxel_communities == l).sum() for l in comm_labels]

    blocks = numpy.zeros((n_voxels, n_voxels), dtype=bool)
    start = 0
    for c in comm_counts:
        blocks[start:start + c, start:start + c] = 1
        start += c

    ix = numpy.empty_like(voxel_communities)
    ix[voxel_communities.argsort()] = numpy.arange(n_voxels)
    blocks[:] = blocks[ix,:]
    blocks[:] = blocks[:,ix]
    return blocks
```

Here's a quick explanation. This uses an inverse indexing trick to reorder the columns and rows of an array of diagonal blocks into the desired matrix.

```
    n_voxels = voxel_communities.size
    comm_labels = sorted(set(voxel_communities))
    comm_counts = [(voxel_communities == l).sum() for l in comm_labels]

    blocks = numpy.zeros((n_voxels, n_voxels), dtype=bool)
    start = 0
    for c in comm_counts:
        blocks[start:start + c, start:start + c] = 1
        start += c
```

These lines are used to construct the initial block matrix. So for example, say you have six voxels and three communities, and each community contains two voxels. Then the initial block matrix will look like this:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This is essentially the same as the desired adjacency matrix *after* the voxels have been sorted by community membership. So we need to reverse that sorting. We do so by constructing an inverse argsort array.

```
    ix = numpy.empty_like(voxel_communities)
    ix[voxel_communities.argsort()] = numpy.arange(n_voxels)
```

Now `ix` will reverse the sorting process when used as an index. And since this is a symmetric matrix, we can perform the reverse sorting operation separately on columns and then on rows:

```
    blocks[:] = blocks[ix,:]
    blocks[:] = blocks[:,ix]
    return blocks
```

Here's an example of the result it generates for a small input:

```
>>> voxel_adjacency(numpy.array([0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2]))
array([[ True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

It seems to me that this does something quite similar to `voxel_matrix[np.ix_(voxels1, voxels2)] = 1` as suggested by [pv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416559/fill-scipy-numpy-matrix-based-on-indices-and-values#comment45170574_28416559), except it does it all at once, instead of tracking each possible combination of nodes.

There may be a better solution, but this should at least be an improvement.

Also, note that if you can simply accept the new ordering of voxels as canonical, then this solution becomes as simple as creating the block array! That takes all of about 300 milliseconds.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much. Unfortunately, the indexes are important, because that represents where the voxels are in the brain. I need to keep those the same to get this information to map back onto the brain. I am going to test both this solution and the one by @pv. and see which one is faster. Thanks everyone!

Comment: One clear disadvantage is the your solution won't work with a scipy.sparse.lil_matrix, right? I am on a cluster of computers with a lot of memory, but I still have to be careful, and the sparse matrices help with that.

Comment: Well, I don't think it will work _well_; but you could always generate the matrix and then convert it to a sparse matrix. And it's possible that it will work for some kinds of sparse matrix... I'll do some experimentation.

Comment: Your method takes 937 seconds on my computing cluster. While voxel_matrix[np.ix_(voxels1, voxels2)] = 1 takes 996 seconds. This is much improved, since it was taking me about an hour to fill it the old way. Thanks so much! This is with 121072 voxels and 278 nodes. This includes making the voxel_community array.